# Adduser to ssh into Aws Ec2

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am testing to setup a Git on the Server (Ec2 - Linux Amazon). All things are going fine but I did one thing that I can not reproduce and I would like to understand.

I am following this tutorial for Git on the Server
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

I created 4 users to test and created their ssh key on server. (User Git) On /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys file, I added the other 3 users public key (id_rsa.pub) to allow them push.

I use this commands to create users and ssh keys. I checked all permissions on /home/username/.ssh folders (700) and authorized_keys (600) file.

```
$ sudo adduser git
$ sudo su - git
$ cd
$ mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I created ssh key on ec2 using the following commands

```
$ ssh-keygen -o
or
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

My question is, why one user I can ssh into ec2 using public-key (id_rsa.pub)? The other 3 users I only can ssh into ec2 using private key (id_rsa)

I am ssh into ec2

```
$ ssh -i username.pem username@public.ip
```

Thanks

Comment: "can ssh into ec2 using public-key" - you always need to use private key, not public. You must be misinterpreting something.

Comment: When a user attempts to connect via SSH, the operating system will look in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If the private key being used to login (provided via `username.pem`) matches the public key stored in the `authorized_keys` file, then the login will be permitted.

Comment: @Marcin, I use the public key by mistake but it worked. I would like to understand why...

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the authorized_keys has all 4 users public keys (id_rsa.pub). And I login with one user with his public key (id_rsa.pub) and the other 3 I login with their private keys (id_rsa).

Comment: You possibly swapped the public & private keypairs. They are effectively interchangeable.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you mean changed? But the private key start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and public key one long line starting with ssh-rsa .... git@ip-number.us-east-2.compute.internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The other 3 users I only can ssh into ec2 using private key (id_rsa)

Double-check that using, with one of the three users:

```
ssh -Tv git@ip-number.us-east-2.compute.internal
```

You will see exactly what ssh is using for its connection.

"They are effectively interchangeable.": John alluded to the fact:

- ssh needs to send the public key to the remote user
- the public key [can be derived from the private key](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66506) ([at least, in practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/105847))
- therefore, you can use one or the other.

Comment: VonC, thanks I think -Tv will help me, I will compare all users.